# Graphs such that contracting an edge decreases the chromatic number

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G = (V,E)$ be a finite, simple, undirected, connected graph, such that contracting an edge reduces the chromatic number. Does this imply that $G$ is complete?

Comment: No, consider an cycle.

Comment: The graphs you are considering are called contraction-critical k-chromatic graphs. There is some literature on the topic, see for example "A contraction theorem for abstract graphs" of Dirac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any odd cycle of length at least 5 is a counterexample.